# Invoke Javascript file from C# application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I have a .js file that performs a fairly simple task of building an array strings. Without going into too much detail, I have found Javascript the best language to perform this specific task.

What I want now is to access that array in my C# application. Javascript cannot access the filesystem, so writing the array to a file before reading it with C# is out of the question.

Is there an easy way to do this? Can these two languages interact at all?

Comment: JSC was always part of .Net... So if you are fine to compile it first you can get normal .Net executable out of your JavaScript... Also unclear why you can't access file system with presumably local JavaScript...

Comment: You tagged this question with Jquery, is this a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a check to a JavaScript parser called Jurassic:

- http://jurassic.codeplex.com/

For example, taken from their docs:

```
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
Console.WriteLine(engine.Evaluate("5 * 10 + 2"));
```

Comment: @user3478799 No problem! You can still mark it as the right answer if you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming local JavaScript on Windows.

You can definitely access files with local JavaScript as with any other scripting language.

Here is sample to create file form [Working with files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) MSDN article:

```
function CreateFile()
{
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var tf = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", true);
   tf.WriteLine("Testing 1, 2, 3.") ;
   tf.Close();
}
```

You can also compile some JavaScript with .Net JSC compiler to get executable (or probably even .Net assembly) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Assuming that this is a web form C# application you can access Javascript function from C# code using `ScriptManager` class which is part of `System.Web.UI`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "GetData", "Javascript:getArrayValues();", true);
 }
```

In the HTML markup define a tag like

```
<asp:HiddenField ID ="hfArrayValues" runat ="server" Value ="" />
```

In getArrayValues() JS function you can store the array value into a hidden variable and then access this value from code behind

```
 function getArrayValues() {
        var arr = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];
        var hfvalue = document.getElementById('hfArrayValues').value = arr;
 }
```

and your C# method where you can access the array values

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Response.Write(hfArrayValues.Value);
 }
```